# Highlight Text Between Labels and Copy to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I have this HTML Code (example) 
and I want JavaScript or Jquery to put the mouse over any word,

1. all text between labels is highlighted
2. by clicking left, all the text (between labels) is automatically copied to the clipboard

Can this be done?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes you can and it is in fact rather common. (most color pickers have that) all you need to do is `document.execCommand('copy')`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard ?  Initial draft, but appears well supported.  But isn't that limited to extensions?

Comment: @DanFarrell In the Web API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand